# SQL optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, collections, plsql

Right now I am facing with an optimization problem.
I have a list of aticles (17000+) and some of them are inactive. The list is provided by the client into an EXCEL file and he asked me to resend them (obviosly only those active).

For this, I have to filter the production database based on the list provided by the customer. Unfortunately, I cannot load the list into a sepparate table from production and then join with master article table but I was able to do this into a UAT database, linked with production one.

The production article master data contains 200 000 000+ rows but filtering it, I can redure to around 80 000 000.

I order to retreive only the active article from production, I was thinking to use collections but it seems the last filter is taking tooooooo long.

Here are my code:

```
declare
    type t_art is table of number index by pls_integer;
    v_art t_art;
    v_filtered t_art;
    idx number := 0;
begin
    for i in (select * from test_table@UAT_DATABASE)
    loop
    idx := idx + 1;
        v_art(idx) := i.art_nr;
    end loop;

    for j in v_art.first .. v_art.last
    loop
        select distinct art_nr
        bulk collect into v_filtered
        from production_article_master_data 
        where status = 0 -- status is active
        and sperr_stat in (0, 2)
        and trunc(valid_until) >= trunc(sysdate)
        and art_nr = v_art(j);
    end loop;
end;
```

Explanation: from UAT database, via DBLink, I am insertinting the list into an ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY in production (v_art). Then, for each value in v_art(17000+ distinct articles), I am filtering with production article master data, returning in 2nd ASSOCITIAVE ARRAY, only the valid articles (there might be 6-8000).

Unfortunately, this filtering action is taking hours.
Can someone provide me some hints how to improve this in orde to decrease the execution time, please?

Thank you,

Comment: Using collections in a loop like this will not work as the `v_filtered` collection will be reinitialised to a new (empty) collection with each iteration calling `BULK COLLECT INTO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use SQL and join the two tables:

```
select distinct p.art_nr
from   production_article_master_data p
       INNER JOIN
       test_table@UAT_DATABASE t
       ON ( p.art_nr = t.art_nr )
where  status = 0 -- status is active
and    sperr_stat in (0, 2)
and    trunc(valid_until) >= trunc(sysdate)
```

If you have to do it in PL/SQL then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numberlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

declare
  -- If you are using Oracle 12c you should be able to declare the
  -- type in the PL/SQL block. In earlier versions you will need to
  -- declare it in the SQL scope instead.

  -- TYPE numberlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

  v_art      NUMBERLIST;
  v_filtered NUMBERLIST;
begin
  select art_nr
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_art
  from test_table@UAT_DATABASE;

  select distinct art_nr
  bulk collect into v_filtered
  from production_article_master_data 
  where status = 0 -- status is active
  and sperr_stat in (0, 2)
  and trunc(valid_until) >= trunc(sysdate)
  and art_nr MEMBER OF v_art;
end;
```

Comment: are you sure that joining 2 tables over DBLink is best solution (taking into consideration that 1st table is very big)?!

Comment: @mikcutu I've also added a PL/SQL version which does not rely on loops. I can't tell you what will be more performant as I do not have access to your databases and network - so you will need to try various options and see.

Comment: Databse version is 11.1.0.7.0<br>
I am not allowed to create objects on production database<br>
... but is seems that the select over the DBLink finised sucessfully in time.